# Rails design multi client app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, multi-tenant

I need some references for creating a Rails app where each client/company has his own database and using some control panel to admin his parameters.
I have used the setler gem, but I need some design advices.
What is the best practice to do this, guys?

(The decision of separating the databases is made by the big size of the data that they store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://www.rollcallapp.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

Multi-client is also known as multi-tenant.
See also answers to this question:

[Multi-tenant rails application: what are the pros and cons of different techniques?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003024/multi-tenant-rails-application-what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-different-techniqu)