# Best Practice for Multidomain Rails Shop Setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing a new rails app which has multiple shops on different domains with just different content. What is the best practice for this?

I'm thinking of running one app and serve to multiple domains and set the shop with `Shop.find_by_domain(request.host)` or something like that.

Or is it better to have one rails app for every domain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much overlap is there between domains? Do different domains share same controllers?

Comment: its pretty much the same site just different content.

Comment: I would use one app and just have different databases and CSS in /public. There may be security concerns if you behave based on `request.host` not to mention proxies, load balancing, and SSL concerns.

Comment: what is the alternative to request.host?

Comment: Are you wanting this because you want to share some table in the database? Or is it something else which you feel beneficial?

Comment: no i want to share the code over the different shops.. the only difference between the shops is the whole content..

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into subdomains?

Here is a good railscast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

And you can use 37 Signals 'pow' gem. You probably don't need different rails apps but rather a multi-tenant application.

Check out shopify.com , that is a big Rails app with the different shop model.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

1. the database content is completely different per sites (including users table)
2. only a limited number of sites (say less than 10)
3. Your app is not service to customer. It's not like Blogger or Shopify. You own the content of your site/customer does not "require" to have custom domain.

If all three points match your scenario, then using multiple domain on a single app seems to only add complexity without much benefit.

On the other hand, if you do want multiple domain, I think reading [Multi-tenant rails application: what are the pros and cons of different techniques?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003024) and https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails can be helpful.